# Scrapy crawl not Crawling any url

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

This is my first spider code. When I executed this code in my cmd. log shows that the urls are not even getting crawled and there were not DEBUG message in them.
Can't be able to find any solution to this problem anywhere.. I am not able to understand what is wrong. can somebody help me with this.

My code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes_spider"

    def start_request(self):

        urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/",
                "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/",
                "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/"
                ]
    
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html'% page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Log:

```
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: my_scrapy)
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 
1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 
2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), 
cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: 
twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'my_scrapy',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'my_scrapy.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['my_scrapy.spiders']}
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 1a9440bbf933d074
2021-06-19 23:19:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
 2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), 
scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 
127.0.0.1:6023
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.008228,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 17, 49, 2, 99933),
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 17, 49, 2, 91705)}
2021-06-19 23:19:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: since @Shivam answered your question already, I just want to mention that you maybe one day come to the point, where you better disable your robots.txt, currently you are following the advices, which are stated in their robots.txt-file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** As I do not have 50 reputation to comment that's why I am answering here.

The problem is in function naming, your function should be `def start_requests(self)` instead of `def start_request(self)`.

The first requests to perform are obtained by calling the start_requests() method which (by default) generates Request for the URLs. But, in your case it never gets into that function due to which the requests are never made for those URLs.

**Your code after small change**

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes_spider"

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/",
                "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/",
                "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/"
                ]
    
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html'% page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```